# How can i SQL Select unique column with group by?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need a product min price with grouped by size and i can do it but when i select one more column like id mysql output a error and i cant select. When i enable only_full_group_by, the outputs are not correct. Sku is a product's barcode and unique.Sku list have product infos like color, type, status.

The table like that:

| barcode | size | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | 120x120 | 12.90 |
| 2222 | 120x120 | 18.90 |
| 3333 | 80x80 | 9.90 |
| 4444 | 80x80 | 12.90 |

And my sql code like that;

```
SELECT  MIN(thecarpet_price) as minPrice,size,sku 
FROM `sku_list` WHERE `design` = 80190 AND
thecarpet_price IS NOT NULL AND status = 1 AND thecarpet = 1 
GROUP BY size  
ORDER BY `size` ASC
```

Expected result:

| barcode | size | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | 120x120 | 12.90 |
| 3333 | 80x80 | 9.90 |

I need group by size and i should get min price with sku. How can i do that ?

Comment: When you grouping by , the select columns need to be on group by clause or part of an aggregation function. I can see that your table is not correct, please post full  table description some insert datas and your expected result based on the data you will provide

Comment: Post `sku_list` table description

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using?

Comment: i guess 7.4.3 @jarlh

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/17227d8/1

Comment: @AlperUluses jarih asking amout MySQL version not php version ;) but here is your solution: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Comment: Mysql version 8.0.23

Comment: @AlperUluses for mysql 8+ version u should use witch clause instead of ProGu solution

Answer (score 1):

```
select t1.barcode,t2.price, t2.size
from tbl_test t1
right join 
(
  select min(price) as price ,size from tbl_test group by size
) t2 on t1.price=t2.price and t1.size=t2.size;
```

Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pB6b5xrgPKCivFWcpQHsyE/25